# Try all available WSDL IPs with JAX-WS

Tags: java, dns, jax-ws

I'm using JAX-WS to open a service port.

When the DNS exposes two IPs for the DNS entry (of the WSDL), the Service tries to use only the first - resulting in a "`Failed to access the WSDL at: http://some.url.com/someDocument?wsdl. It failed with: 
 Connection refused: connect`" exception.

I've found an [issue filed against JAX-WS](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-556), but with no resolution.
this is the [comment that describes my problem best](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAX_WS-556?focusedCommentId=17270&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_17270).

The code is just a one-liner:

```
Service service = Service.create("http://some.url.com/someDocument?wsdl", engineQName);
```

the smarts is in exposing those two A records on `http://some.url.com/` at the DNS.

Can anyone help?
10x,

Answer (score 0):

From the comments in the bug you filed, seems rather more like a bug in `HttpUrlConnection` than in JAX-WS. However, I don't really know how you can change that, maybe by giving a custom HttpUrlConnection to JAX-WS, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: last comment in the bug report linked in your question

Comment: yeh, the assignee asks repeatedly for a SSCCE. but the no bug has been filed for HttpURLConnection, afaik.